# How to detect user inactivity in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to fire a method when users is not using chrome (say after 5mins) and fire another when user becomes active. How to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome has a dedicated API, [chrome.idle](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/idle), to detect idle state.

```
chrome.idle.queryState(
  5 * 60, // seconds
  function(state) {
    if (state === "active") {
      // Computer not locked, user active in the last 5 minutes
    } else {
      // Computer is locked, or the user was inactive for 5 minutes
    }
  }
);
```

It also provides an event, `chrome.idle.onStateChanged`, to notify you when the state changes. If you want to know whether the user is inactive in a browser window, you can see the post - [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for it in chrome.tabs.

Comment: What is considered as _idle_ here? Say, if I minimize all Chrome windows and move my mouse cursor around, is it “_idle_” for Chrome?